# Postgres - Pass dynamically generated date to where clause

Tags: postgresql, date, where-clause

I need to generate series of date till current_date based on job's last run date

- last run date ='2022-10-01'
- current date = '2022-10-05'

generate date like

```
varchar dynamic_date = '2022-10-01','2022-10-02','2022-10-03','2022-10-04','2022-10-05'
```

and pass to where to clause

```
select * 
from t1 
where created_date in (dynamic_date)
```

this is not allowed as dynamic_date is varchar and created_date is date column

trying to find efficient way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()`

```
select * 
from t1 
where created_date in (select g.dt::date
                       from generate_series(date '2022-10-01', 
                                            current_date, 
                                            interval '1 day') as g(dt)
                      )
```

Or even simpler:

```
select * 
from t1 
where created_date >= date '2022-10-01'
  and created_date <= current_date
```

Comment: thank you! above solution will work